# How to find strings with unclosed quotation mark using regular expression

Tags: regex

For example, my input is this:

*Hello Davis, Susan said "She had to run errands". Sara was there and said "Do you need any help? But I replied "No, I'm good."*

I need to find any strings without closed quotation mark. In here, the string is *Do you need any help?*.

Comment: In your example, this might not be actually possible with just regex. How would your regex know when the sentence is supposed to end, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Khauri McClain mentioned, this is not full proof. If you use something like:

(\s[\"]+[a-zA-Z0-9 \,]+[.!\?])+([\s]{1})

for the search expression in your example, and \1\"\2 for the replace expression it does work for your example. I pasted several lines into a text editor and replaced the missing \" as shown below in the first two lines.

**Replaced**

Hello Davis, Susan said "She had to run errands". Sara was there and said "Do you need any help?" But I replied "No, I'm good."

Hello Davis, Susan said "She had to run errands". Sara was there and said "Do you need any help?" But I replied "No, I'm good."

**Not Replaced**

Hello Davis, Susan said "She had to run errands". Sara was there and said "Do you need any help? But I replied "No, I'm good."

You really need to know punctuation rules or this approach will be more than brittle.

For example, "She had to run errands". should normally end with ...errands."

So if you are not careful, you can make a real mess of things.

**Edit:** I wanted to add one more thing. I recently did some similar editing on a number of documents (15), but I had to break the problem down to multiple passes. Each pass dealt with a single replace case.

If I had many docs and my life depended on the accuracy, I would have written a program to do the editing. My last 2 cents worth.

Answer (score 2):

No. The best you could do is match lines with a single quotation mark, but that would then flag multi-line quotes as problems. What you are asking for would require intelligent language parsing, which is not available.